# Adding namespace limits results Linq to XML

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

Ive read a few articles on Linq to XML and either ive picked it up wrong or missing some piece of the puzzle.

What im trying to achieve is to load some XML, get required data by different named fields and nodes/elements. Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata created="2014-05-15T12:26:07.701Z" xmlns="http://site/cu-2.0#" xmlns:ext="http://site/cu/b-2.0">
  <customer-list count="47" offset="0">
    <customer id="7123456" type="Cust" ext:mark="1">
      <name>Tony Watt</name>
      <sort-name>Watt, Tony</sort-name>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <country>US</country>
      <knownAs-list>
        <knownAs locale="ko" sort-name="Tony Watt"</knownAs>
        <knownAs locale="ja" sort-name="Watt Tony"</knownAs>
      </knownAs-list>
    </customer>
    <tag-list>
        <tag count="1">
          <name>Country</name>
        </tag>
        <tag count="1">
          <name>usa</name>
        </tag>
  <customer id="9876543" type="Cust" ext:mark="2">
```

So i can load the XML and i can display data. Heres a snippet of the code

```
    Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://site/cu-2.0#"
    Dim XDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(SomeXML)

    For Each c As XElement In XDoc.Descendants(ns + "name")
        Response.Write(c)
    Next
```

So this displays all the elements with "name". The problem i have here is i want the customer name but not the tag-list country name (see last few lines of the XML)

Ideally i want to return all the details for each customer but adding the namespace limits the me to all the elements with name when i want other data too. If i remove the namespace i get no results returned so im unsure what to do next?

Ive read a ton of articles but i cant seem to work out what needs to be done or if ive gone down the wrong path? Please remember i have tried other methods which i can post if anyone likes but after reading MSDN and other articles i think ive confused myself or missed out a step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want to use

```
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://site/cu-2.0#"
Dim XDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(SomeXML)

For Each c As XElement In XDoc.Descendants(ns + "customer")
    Response.Write(c.Element(ns + "name").Value)
Next
```

Comment: This has returned results and is very close to what im after. If i change the Response.Write line to (a label) Label1.Text += ar.Element(ns + "name").Value & ar.Element(ns + "country").Value & "<br />" then i get Object not set to an instance error (otherwise i get the name returned if i remove the second half of the code)

Comment: That suggests that there are some `customer` elements that don't have a `country` child element. So you might want to adapt the code to use `Label1.Text += CStr(ar.Element(ns + "name")) + "; " + CStr(ar.Element(ns + "country")) + "<br>"`, exploiting the conversion/casting that `XElement` allows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get name from customer give this a try

```
    Dim xe As XElement =
        <customer-list count="47" offset="0">
            <customer id="7123456" type="Cust" mark="1">
                <name>Tony Watt</name>
                <sort-name>Watt, Tony</sort-name>
                <gender>male</gender>
                <country>US</country>
                <knownAs-list>
                    <knownAs locale="ko" sort-name="Tony Watt"></knownAs>
                    <knownAs locale="ja" sort-name="Watt Tony"></knownAs>
                </knownAs-list>
            </customer>
            <customer id="1" type="Cust" mark="1">
                <name>Fred Flintstone</name>
                <sort-name>Flintstone, Fred</sort-name>
                <gender>male</gender>
                <country>US</country>
                <knownAs-list>
                    <knownAs locale="ko" sort-name="Fred Flintstone"></knownAs>
                    <knownAs locale="ja" sort-name="Flintstone Fred"></knownAs>
                </knownAs-list>
            </customer>
            <tag-list>
                <tag count="1">
                    <name>Country</name>
                </tag>
                <tag count="1">
                    <name>usa</name>
                </tag>
            </tag-list>
        </customer-list>

    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From c As XElement In xe.Elements
                                         Where c.Name.LocalName = "customer"
                                         Select c From n As XElement In c.Elements
                                                  Where n.Name.LocalName = "name" Select n


    For Each r As XElement In ie
        Debug.WriteLine(r.Value)
    Next
```

Comment: Sorry this had no results returned.

Comment: 'This' as in the example or when you added it to your code?